# Two Raspi4 different responses on Socket Programming to PC

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, python-sockets

I have 2 Raspberry Pi 4 units.Both have been updated and upgraded and both flashed with rasbian lite. I created a really simply script, on the first raspi which connects to my pc on port 5999 and performs a basic function of grabbing the time and sending that on said port. My pc accepts it, prints it and writes it to a file. The second raspi has the exact same script with same permissions etc and the script does not work. No errors etc returned. I would for example run the server side on my pc, run the client side on the first raspi, works 100%, disconnect and run the same script on second raspi and no response on server side or client side. I have check "netstat -a"command, port listening etc on pc, have changed the port numbers on one and both raspis' but still cannot get the first raspi to send data.

Any similar experiences? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should share some code examples.

Comment: Ok will do now, the code is the same for both raspberry pi units.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, sorry guys, thx anyway for reply, omitted the 6 in the LAN IP address in the code on one of the raspberry Pi units.

If anyone wants the code then I will post, client and server working on PI4 units. Just let me know in comments.